# Applications of real-space renormalizaton group (RG)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, renormalization, ising-model, lattice-model

I'm looking for lattice models on which real-space RG can be applied fairly simply to get decent results. In particular, I'm looking for something like the classical 2D Ising model on a triangular lattice (treated in Goldenfeld's book) or the quantum Ising model in 1D (treated for instance in Continentino's book). It seems to me that complexity grows rapidly when a model other than Ising's is considered.

Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2015.00046/full: an application on the 2D Ising and Potts Model

Comment: http://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Refael-RSRG-lecture-updated.pdf. Real Space RG on 1D disordered systems by Yale Summer School

Comment: https://www.pnas.org/content/114/13/3328 Real Space Renormalization group theory on disordered glasses.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aaf489 Applications on the Random Quantum Ising model

Comment: These comments would make a valid answer, I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, here are my comments as an answer:

(1)
https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2015.00046/full

An application on the 2D Ising and Potts Model

(2) http://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Refael-RSRG-lecture-updated.pdf

Real Space RG on 1D disordered systems by Yale Summer School

(3) https://www.pnas.org/content/114/13/3328

Real Space Renormalization group theory on disordered glasses.

(4) https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aaf489

Applications on the Random Quantum Ising model